# Python: Trying to execute a function using values from another function

Tags: python, function

Trying, to get the second function - sum columns to add each index in both list of lists (over_50k & under_50k) what i dont understand is how to take both lists from the training_list function and use them in the second function - sum_columns, below is my code. I'm pretty new to all this so any step by step feedback would be greatly appreciated.

when executing the code, im getting the following error,
  File "C:/Python34/Lib/rerun.py", line 12, in main
    over_50k, under_50k = trainging_list()
TypeError: 'function' object is not iterable

---

```
def main():
    def trainging_list():

        over_50k = [[1, 2, 3, 4], [3, 4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9, 8]]
        under_50k = [[1, 4, 6, 8], [3, 7, 4, 5], [6, 9, 4, 5]]
        print(over_50k)
        return over_50k, under_50k

    over_50k, under_50k = trainging_list()

    def sum_columns(over_50k, under_50k):
        print("a")
        over_50k_sum_list = [sum(k) for k in zip(*over_50k)]
        under_50k_sum_list = [sum(k) for k in zip(*under_50k)]
        sums = over_50k_sum_list + under_50k_sum_list
        print(sums)
        return sums
main()
```

Comment: You need to return the two lists, i.e. `return over_50k,under_50k`. Then you just call `sum_columns(over_50k,under_50k)`. If you wanna make it more readable you could rename the parameters in sum_columns since it doesn't depend on their size. (It'll help you see the difference between [parameters and arguments](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parameter_%28computer_programming%29#Parameters_and_arguments)). Also, trainging --> training?

Comment: Hi Keyser, sorry ive updated the code. So when i run the code it only generates the over_50k list. It doesnt move onto the next function, any ideas why?

Comment: Yes, well, you haven't called it. You've *defined* a function, but you haven't used it yet. when you do `.. = trainging_list()` you're calling that function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your method `trainging_list()` returns the function object itself, which can't be assigned to two variables. You probably wanted to return the two lists:

```
def trainging_list():
    over_50k = [[1, 2, 3, 4], [3, 4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9, 8]]
    under_50k = [[1, 4, 6, 8], [3, 7, 4, 5], [6, 9, 4, 5]]
    print(over_50k)
    return over_50k, under_50k
```

Then you define the next function, which is never actually executed because you need to call it with your lists:

```
over_50k, under_50k = trainging_list()

def sum_columns(over_50k, under_50k):
    # your code

sum = sum_columns(over_50k, under_50k)
```

Comment: Hi pascalhein, sorry ive updated the code. So when i run the code it only generates the over_50k list. It doesnt move onto the next function, any ideas why?

Comment: @Python_rookie I updated my answer, you need to call the function you just defined to make it print the result.

Comment: Thank you pascalhein, understand it now